# snr of awgn in matlab before and after filtration

Tags: matlab, noise, snr

I'm studying a system's transient characteristics with awgn added to an input signal and I need to calculate $\text{SNR}$ before and after filtration.

Here is my code to generate input and output:

```matlab
K0=1.2;
b=[0 K0];
a=[1 K0-1];
N=10000;
n=1:N;
uinp=[1 ones(1,N-1)];
sn=0   ;               % SNR on input signal
levs=0  ;              
uinp=awgn(uinp,sn,levs);   
uout=filter(b, a, uinp);
```

The input signal has an $\text{SNR}$ equal to $1$ (or $0\, \text{dB}$).
How can I calculate the $\text{SNR}$ of the output signal?

I've tried to calculate the noise power (as without noise, the mean equals 1 after the transient, so I can just divide), but not sure if it is correct:

```matlab
sum((uout-mean(uout)).^2)/length(uout) % = 1.5366
sum((uinp-mean(uinp)).^2)/length(uinp) %= 1.0236
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the [MATLAB SNR Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html)?

Comment: I've tried it, assuming that f(signal+noise)=f(signal)+f(noise) where f is a filter function. Looks true enough, but I'm not sure

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here.  My advice is to run the examples that MATLAB provides for awgn() and snr().

Comment: I've did it using `snr(signal,noise)`, where `signal` is if `filter` signal without noise, and `noise` is `filter` `noisedSignal-clearSignal`